# Why am I getting a CORS error using webpack?

Tags: javascript, cors, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use the `Spotify` web api with a simple `react` app being bundled with `webpack`.

First of all here is the demo app straight from Spotify. It is very simple.  It calls an `express` server with a link like this:

```
<a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Log in with Spotify</a>
```

And then runs this `redirect` in the express server.

```
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
      res.cookie(stateKey, state);
      var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
      res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
        querystring.stringify({
          response_type: 'code',
          client_id: client_id,
          scope: scope,
          redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
          state: state
        }));
    });
```

which calls another endpoint, the `redirect_url`.  This all works fine.

Here is what happens when I `bundle` with `webpack` and then call the `/login` endpoint from my `store`.

My link is the same, but it now calls a click function, which calls this function in my `store`:

```
function _login(auth, callback) {
    request.get('/login')
        .end(function(res) {
            callback(res);
        });
}
```

That calls the `login` enpoint.  When the `redirect` is then called, I get a `cors` error.

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The `express` enpoint is the same exact code.  I literally copied and pasted it to my store.  Why would I now get this error, but not with vanilla js?  Why is my redirect not working?  I thought I understood `cors`.

Comment: If you are on localhost, then this could be expected. When you first created your app as a spotify app you properly setup what `redirect_url` for spotify to expect. If you can you should include localhost as well here.